# How can I find out which extension contributes a specific suggestion in VS Code and whether it can be changed by a setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What's the best way to identify which Visual Studio Code setting is generating / allowing various suggestions to pop up (so it can be turned off)?  In particular I'd like to eliminate these three from ever showing.

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to disable Intellisense completely or disable it from suggesting specific things?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin specific things.  Those three things in particular, and ideally see some sort of generalized way to see what sets of suggestions there are, and disable as needed

Comment: Gotcha. I tried deleting instances of `PromiseRejectionEvent` in the vscode installation directory, and oddly that did not prevent the suggestion from occurring. Hmm. I wonder why you received a down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those suggestions are types from the standard library. The TypeScript service that powers VS Code's JavaScript and TypeScript language features loads these types from `.d.ts` files in order to understand the signatures of standard JavaScript library functions such as `parseInt` or `Promise`.

To find out where a type is coming from, try using workspace symbol search (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

In this case, these types come from the standard `lib.d.ts` file that TypeScript loads automatically. TypeScript will also automatically load a `d.ts` file for the DOM api.

To disable these suggestions, create a `jsconfig.json` at the root of your project with the contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": []
    }
}
```

This tells typescript not to include any extra typings files for the core libraries. You can also select which typings you want to include:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2015"
        ]
    }
}
```

See [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for a list of valid `lib` options

If you notice any bugs with this behavior or have any suggestions on how this could be improved, please [file an issue against VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)

---

**Update**

To discover where a type suggestion is coming from, you may also be able to write:

```
 /**
  * @type {AsyncResultObjectCallback}
  */
 var placeholer;
```

And then run `go to type definition` on `placeholder`. Even using `"lib": []`, you may still be seeing suggestions from `@types` files or node packages that include `d.ts` files

Comment: Thanks as always.  You happen to where `AsyncResultObjectCallback` is coming from?  The search menu you mentioned does not find it, but it seems to show up in the suggestion list.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how you may also be able to use `go to type definition` to discover where a type suggestion is coming from. In your case, I suspect `AsyncResultObjectCallback` is coming from a `d.ts` file from some library but tracking down which one can be difficult

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the boring way and just do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) (use the `Help: Start Extension Bisect` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)).

But if you're the kind of person who likes dissections, I offer you the following educational experience:

1. Open the VS Code devtools (`Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))
2. Open the "Sources" tab and go open "Electron Isolated Context" > ".../resources/app" (or whatever the path to app resources is for your VS Code installation) > out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js.
3. <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and search for `"unknown_provider"` and put a breakpoint where the search result is. This will use the source map and open up the corresponding source, which is in the file we want- [src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/browser/suggest.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/browser/suggest.ts). Scroll down to the line that says `return new CompletionItemModel` and put a breakpoint there.
4. In the VS Code editor, go to the place of interest and trigger suggestions (<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> if you've not remapped it to something else). This will trigger the breakpoint we just made.
5. In the variables section of the debugger, find the `results` variable (an array of all the suggestions) and expand it. For each entry, you can expand it to view its properties. The property of interest is the `completion` property, which has an `extensionId` property. That's the thing you want.

   Note that you can also right click things in the variables section of the debugger and in the context menu that appears, select "store object as global variable", which will let you play with that variable in the console panel of the devtools.