# Disable intellisense for default typescript libraries in VSCODE

Tags: typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

In visual studio code, using typescript, I get unwanted suggestions when using the intellisense/autocomplete feature.

Examples:

```
HTMLAllCollection
DOMError

etc...
```

The reason seems to be that intellisense automatically includes all files in

```
{vscode dir}/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib
```

Is there any way to disable intellisense for these?

In the end I want intellisense to only include things that are explicitly related to my project.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850267/configure-visual-studio-code-suggestions/43859901#43859901 and others

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/73364860/11107541

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to control which libraries are loaded in your project and are providing intellisense/autocomplete you need to configure `lib` property *[array type]* of `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

If `lib` property is *not configured*, TypeScript will *automatically* load following libraries:

- For target **ES5**: DOM, ES5, ScriptHost.
- For target **ES6**: DOM, ES6, DOM.Iterable, ScriptHost.

Example configuration in `tsconfig.json` file could look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ]
  }
}
```

This would load only libraries for ECMAScript 2017 intellisense.

You can read more about compiler options, including `lib` here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 4):

Open the Settings `editor File > Preferences > Settings (Code > Preferences > Settings` on `macOS`

**snippets** **:**
To disable basic TypeScript snippets you can set `editor.snippetSuggestions` to `"none"` in your [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) file. If you'd like to see snippets, you can specify the order relative to suggestions; at the top `("top")`, at the bottom `("bottom")`, or inlined ordered alphabetically `("inline")`. The default is `"inline"`
[image]

**JSDoc support:**
To disable JSDoc comment suggestions in TypeScript, set `"typescript.suggest.completeJSDocs": false`
[image]

**Auto imports:**
You can disable auto imports by setting `"typescript.autoImportSuggestions.enabled": false`
[image]

**Formatting:**
set `"typescript.format.enable"` to `false` to disable it.

**JSX and auto-closing tags:**
Set `"typescript.autoClosingTags"` to `false` to disable JSX tag closing.
[image]

**Unused variables and unreachable code:**
To disable fading out of unused code, set `"editor.showUnused"` to `false`. You can also disable fading of unused code only in TypeScriptScript by setting,

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.showUnused":  false
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.showUnused":  false
},
```

[image]

**Code suggestions:**
Set "`typescript.suggestionActions.enabled`" to `false` to disable suggestions.
[image]

You can read more on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript