# How can I make VS Code not assume the DOM APIs are available?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, dom

By default, when editing a JavaScript file in VS Code, it will assume that the `fetch` function and related types exist in the current context.  This makes sense for JavaScript designed to run in the browser, but when running on node.js the `fetch` function does not exist unless it is installed via `node-fetch`.  I find that in this context, VS Code is misleading, as it will not highlight an error when you trying calling the `fetch` function, or access other types such as `Request` and `Response`, even though they do not exist unless you have `node-fetch` installed.

How can I configure VS Code to assume a node.js context, and therefore assume that `fetch` does not exist unless I explicitly import it from `node-fetch`?

Comment: FYI `fetch` _is_ available in NodeJS v18

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  I'm currently tied to v16 but interesting to know that won't be the case forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why web types are there by default

From the docs for [`tsconfig.json compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib):

> TypeScript includes a default set of type definitions for built-in JS APIs (like `Math`), ***as well as type definitions for things found in browser environments (like `document`)***.

### How to change the defaults

Create a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) or [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig), and set the [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) array to *not* contain "DOM", which means that [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) (the "DOM standard library" type definitions file that comes with TypeScript) will not be assumed. You should specify which ECMA Script standard you want to write your source code in.

The config file also has fields to control what files it takes effect on: [`files`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files), [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include), and [`exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude). If you specify none of them, [`include` will default to `**`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include), which matches everything beside and recursively under subdirectories beside the config file.

Having to create this file could be seen as annoying if you just want to write a single JS file (ie. now you have a whole config file just for one source file!). I don't know if there are alternatives that are more convenient for such a use case. If anyone knows, please edit this answer.

- I looked briefly into [TypeScript triple-slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), which allow specifying things on a per-file basis, but I think you can only *add* things (ie. I don't think you can use them to remove a `lib`).
- At the time of this writing, there are VS Code settings that can be applied at the user-settings scope that affect settings for implicit projects (JS/TS files which don't have a project config file) (`js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.*`), but none of them are for setting the `compileOptions.lib` field, and my gut says it's probably not going to happen (but don't quote me on that).

### You probably also want types for the Node API

TypeScript bundles types for web APIs, but not for the NodeJS APIs. Use NPM to install a version of [`@types/node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node). Make sure the major version number of the version you install matches the major version number of the version of NodeJS you want to script to be runnable on.

### Fun irrelevant facts to this question

Continuing on the point about VS Code's user-settings for implicit projects, VS Code puts some defaults in effect (on top of those that TypeScript itself does) if no project is detected. You can poke through the code at [github.dev/microsoft/vscode](https://github.dev/microsoft/vscode) by doing "Find in Files", using `extensions/typescript-language-features/**/*` as the "files to include" field, and `compilerOptions` as the find query. `compilerOptions.lib` seems to *not* be something that VS Code touches in such a scenario.

Comment: Would you be able to update the "Fun irrelevant facts to this question" section of your answer? It currently finds 24 results, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for. Thanks.