# How can I make VS Code always show all inline details in the suggestion widget?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-completion

In VS Code, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger suggestion (at least that's what I use for *Trigger Suggest* command). The command will show the suggestion; e.g., using it on an object will show it's method and properties.

It will also show the type hint only for the currently selected suggestion. How can I make it to show all type hint for all suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're at the mercy of however the extension of interest is implementing suggestions using the VS Code API.

It's a bit complicated and there's some history involved. The relevant extension API points include [`CompletionItemProvider<T>`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider%3CT%3E), [`CompletionItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem), and [`CompletionItemLabel`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemLabel). `CompletionItem` has [`detail?: string`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.detail), [`documentation?: string | MarkdownString`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.documentation), and [`label: string | CompletionItemLabel`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.label).

> Providers can delay the computation of the [detail](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.detail) and [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.documentation) properties by implementing the [resolveCompletionItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider.resolveCompletionItem)-function.

When the `CompletionItemLabel` form of `label` is used and its `description` and/or `detail` properties are populated, those are always rendered for the suggestion in the inline details portion of the suggestion widget- regardless of whether the suggestion is the currently selected one. Otherwise, the `CompletionItem`'s `detail` property is rendered in the inline details portion of the suggestion widget for the currently selected suggestion only (probably due to the complication of `resolveCompletionItem`), and only when the suggestion details panel is toggled off/closed (when it is toggled on/open, the `CompletionItem`'s `detail` and `documentation` are rendered in the suggestion details panel if they exist).

If you're interested in figuring out exactly what your extension of interest is doing, you can always go read its source code (if it's open-source), or you can [dissect your VS Code as it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77406089/11107541) to figure it out.

Note that you can toggle whether inline details are rendered at all for the suggest widget using the `editor.suggest.showInlineDetails` setting, which defaults to `true`.

If you're interested in the history of how this `CompletionItemLabel` thing came about, see [Consider showing completion item detail if available for all list items #39441](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/39441), which I found by googling "`github vscode issues suggestion inline details for all labels always`".