How to display variable type information in VS Code intellisense?
In my VS Code, I cannot get the variable type information in intellisense like in the below screenshot. In the screenshot, the oddOrEvent variable has type information const oddOrEvent: ComputerRed<"even" | "odd">
Screenshot
How can I turn it on? Thank you very much.

related and potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77608184/11107541
